# How Do I Troubleshoot Using an SSH Tunnel From Pythonanywhere to DBeaver?

Tags: mysql, pythonanywhere, dbeaver

I'm trying to connect to my Pythonanywhere database using DBeaver. I've followed the guide on the guide [here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingMySQLFromOutsidePythonAnywhere/) from Pyhtonanwhere and can't find any other solutions online. When I test the tunnel configuration I get the following error.

[DBeaver error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDzsC.png)

As you can see from the panel behind the error, the configuration is as detailed on the Pythonanywhere guide. I have reset my password to ensure my credentials are correct and disabled my firewall and anti virus. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a paid account? Are you able to open a normal ssh connection to your PythonAnywhere account (without the database stuff)?

Comment: Yes, I have a paid account but not sure how to open a normal ssh connection.

Comment: We have a help page: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/SSHAccess/

Comment: I have the same problem @JamesWalshe.  One difference to your screenshot: I think that the first port number given should be 3306, not 22.  I can't see where to enter the MySQL hostname as set out in the PA instructions